# MYSQL data insert query is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to insert some data from a form to a database table "sumation". But it's not working. I use PhpStorm IDE and it's shows no data sources are configured to run this sql and sql dialect is not configured. Where is the problem ?

```
<?php
    $db= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;cahrset=utf8','root','');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $first=$_POST['first'];
        $second=$_POST['second'];
        $third=$_POST['third'];

        $sql="INSERT INTO sumation VALUES($id,'$first','$second','$third')";
        $db->query($sql);
        echo("<script>alert('Data Inserted Sucessfully !')</script>");
    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
        ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
        First: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
        Second: <input type="text" name="second"><br>
        Third: <input type="text" name="third"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" name="submit">Insert </button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting any errors??

Comment: I also suggest escaping dangerous characters in the user input or you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: No errors. Even the javascript code inside the echo is working. But it don't insert any data in database table.

Comment: cahrset, you probably meant charset, injection here are pretty at risk.. AND turn on error reporting to report error?

Comment: What can I do @Parsa Akbari

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php get you started on some basics to avoid sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, the syntax of `INSERT` is

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

So your query would look like

```
INSERT INTO sumation (id, first, second, third) VALUES ($id, '$first', '$second', '$third')
```

You also just *assume* that your query is executed. A PDO query would return an object on success, and boolean `false` on failure, meaning that you could wrap it into an `if`-statement.

You should also read up on [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), which basically means that you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sumation VALUES($id,'$first','$second','$third')";
```

Just replace

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sumation (id,first,second,third) VALUES ($id,'$first','$second','$third')";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $second=$_POST['second'];
    $third=$_POST['third'];

    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO sumation (id,first,second,third) VALUES ($id,'$first','$second','$third')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo("<script>alert('Data Inserted Sucessfully !')</script>");
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    First: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
    Second: <input type="text" name="second"><br>
    Third: <input type="text" name="third"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" name="submit">Insert </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly answer your question on how to protect your application from SQL injection attacks.

An SQL injection attack is where a user inserts SQL commands into their input string allowing them to run SQL queries on your database. This means they can drop the whole database or print out all the rows.

You can use the PDO quote function.

```
$id=$db->quote($_POST['id']);
$first=$db->quote($_POST['first']);
$second=$db->quote($_POST['second']);
$third=$db->quote($_POST['third']);
```

Alternatively I would recommend you use PDO prepare and execute functions read documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php